# Show public methods only in IDEA Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes I just want to know the public interface of a class, but `File Structure`(`Cmd-F12`) always show all methods(and fields) to me.

Could I filter them by modifiers, such as public, protected or private?

Answer (score 26):

There is a "structure view" (Alt-7) which shows class members, and it has sort options, so it will show public methods at the top.

Comment: @Cpt.Senkfuss An option is just "sort", and when it sorts, it puts public at the top of list

Comment: not for me. toggled sort, changed a method to private: no effect. it should've moved below the public ones

Comment: NO: the ``Structure`` view does not tell you whether a Scala function is public, protected or private. it works as expected with Java classes, though. In case a Scala class extends a Java class, it can show in a single view all functions/methods of the entire tree. Methods in Java classes will show you icons for visibility but functions from Scala classes will not give you a clue.

Answer (score 8):

In IntelliJ 2017.1.2, the [Structure View](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structure-tool-window-file-structure-popup.html) (Alt-7 or Cmd-7) includes a `Show non-public` toggle that can be used to filter out private (etc) members.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only look at "lock icon" :

- green lock > public
- red lock > private
- grey key > protected
- grey dot > internal